# RC-Service show a Error on Alpine Linux

Tags: gnome, startup, alpine-linux

today, I wanted to start something with the rc-service command, but the show the error: `* Call to flock failed: Bad file descriptor
 * WARNING: PROGRAM is already starting`. How can I fix it? It is everytime, when I start something.

Comment: Is this a custom openrc file that you made? If yes, can you post it?

Comment: Have you solved it ? I have same problem

Comment: Nope, sadly I didn’t got it to work

Comment: @RedPro : which version of alpine? Which arch? Which service are you trying to start? Is this a custom openrc file?